# Building the folds in WEKA

Tags: weka, cross-validation

> In k-fold cross-validation, the original sample is randomly
>   partitioned into k subsamples

How can I manually choose what instances each subsample is?

Comment: Why would you want to manually choose the instances? Random partitioning is part of the definition of the algorithm.

Comment: Well then what to do if let's say every 5 instances belong to the same data? That is, I am getting 5 vectors (instances) from every window of the data. I don't want to merge them in one vector (thus one instance) in order to have more freedom; that is getting 5 predictions for the same data is better for me than getting one prediction, since in the first case I can say for example if at least two out of the five is predicted positive then the data is positive and then compare the results with when saying at least three and so on..

Comment: The problem I am facing is that when WEKA is randomly picking the instances, it is taking let's say 3 of the instances out of the 5 instances that belong to that window ( along with other instances) and then testing on the others.. and this is not practical in real life since the whole five should either be fed for training or testing..

Comment: Are you using the GUI, or coding with the WEKA library?